# OSGi Bundle in Felix - ClassNotFoundException for Jetty class loaded by name

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, jetty-9

pom.xml:

```
<Import-Package>
         org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server,*
</Import-Package>
```

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Import-Package: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server;version="[9.2,10)"
```

Exception in Logs:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketServerFactory

Felix Web Console:

> Imported Packages org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server,version=9.2.6 from 
>   org.apache.felix.http.jetty (39)

Relevant code in org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServletFactory:

```
Class<WebSocketServletFactory> wssf = (Class<WebSocketServletFactory>)loader
                    .loadClass("org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketServerFactory");
```

Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The question is, where you get the "loader" from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ran into the same problem, and asked on the Felix mailing list. As pointed out by Balazs, it has to do with the "loader" part.
The thread at http://www.mail-archive.com/users%40felix.apache.org/msg16222.html contains a URL to some examples in which the ContextClassLoader is used.

With thanks to Paul, basically you need something like this:

```
// Cache the current classloader
ClassLoader ccl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
// Find the classloader used by the bundle providing jetty
ClassLoader classLoader = jettyBundle.getClassLoader();
// Set the classloader
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader);

// Register the servlet
httpService.registerServlet("/servletName", new MyWebSocketServlet(), null, null);         

// Restore the classloader
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(ccl);
```

See the examples for more complete code.